# jQuery .wrap() adjacent button HTML

Tags: html, jquery

I'm using

```
jQuery( ".quantity" ).wrap( "<div class=\"engrave_button\"></div>" )
```

to wrap the `quantity` div with the `engrave_button` div.

But I need to include the `button` inside the `engrave_button` div. How can I do that?

Current HTML:

```
  <form>
  ....      
  <div class="engrave_button">
        <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" id="quantity_" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
        </div>
      </div> // closing engrave_button div
      <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="123456" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
    </form>
```

Needed HTML:

```
      <form>
      ....
      <div class="engrave_button">
        <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" id="quantity_" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="123456" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
      </div> // move closing engrave_button div here
    </form>
```

Comment: In your "current html" example you have three closing div tags but only two opening div tags

Comment: Thanks, I missed that extra div

Comment: Also there's a closing `</form>` tag, which is never opened in the posted code.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), pass all the element selectors you want to wrap inside the function

```
jQuery(".quantity, .single_add_to_cart_button").wrapAll("<div class=\"engrave_button\"></div>")
```

---

<kbd>**Working Code**</kbd>

```js
jQuery(".quantity, .single_add_to_cart_button").wrapAll("<div class=\"engrave_button\"></div>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="engrave_button">
  <div class="quantity">
    <input type="number" id="quantity_" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
  </div>
</div> // closing engrave_button div
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="123456" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could use wrapAll and include all the selectors to be wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer I thought I'd offer an alternative approach; given your posted HTML it's relatively simple to bring the `<button>` element inside of the `div.quantity` element in both jQuery *and* JavaScript.

First, jQuery:

```js
// selecting the element(s), and then chaining the
// append() method, using its anonymous function:
$('div.engrave_button').append(function() {
  // returning the the next <button> element (if any)
  // to the append() method, which will append to the
  // current '$(this)':
  return $(this).next('button');
});

// showing the updated HTML of the <form> element for
// easy reference:
$('#result').text(function() {
  return $('form').prop('outerHTML');
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.engrave_button {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

#result {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="engrave_button">
    <div class="quantity">
      <input type="number" id="quantity_" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- closing engrave_button div -->
  <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="123456" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And in JavaScript:

```js
// retrieve a NodeList of all elements matching the CSS selector:
const engrave_button_divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.engrave_button');

// iterate over the NodeList of elements using NodeList.prototype.forEach(),
// along with an Arrow function:
engrave_button_divs.forEach((element) => {
  // 'element' is a reference to the current Node of the NodeList over
  // which we're iterating (this variable can be assigned any name you
  // prefer).
  // Here we retrieve the nextElementSibling of the current element:
  let nextElement = element.nextElementSibling,
    // here we check that the nextElement is a <button>, using
    // the element.matches() method:
    nextElementIsButton = nextElement.matches('button');
  // if that nextElement is a <button>:
  if (nextElementIsButton) {
    // we use the Element.append() method to append that <button> to
    // the current (the div.engrave) element:
    element.append(nextElement);
  }
});

document.querySelector('#result').innerText = document.querySelector('form').outerHTML;
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.engrave_button {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

#result {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="engrave_button">
    <div class="quantity">
      <input type="number" id="quantity_" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- closing engrave_button div -->
  <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="123456" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - Arrow functions.
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
  - [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting that I could move the button; and the plain JavaScript is interesting.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed @BlueDogRanch; moving the button, or other contents, is effectively what the `wrap()` method of jQuery does internally. But there's always a different approach that can be taken; it all comes down to your own preferences and the performance.